# AngularJS, why doesn't $http.get fire in my data service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

Code:

```
app.service('dataServices', function ($http) {
    ...
    this.getBases = function (lat, lng) {
        var promise = $http.get('/app/nearestbase/?lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng);
        promise.error(function (msg) { console.log(msg); });
        return promise;
    };
});

// root controller
function RootCtrl($scope, $location, dataServices) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
        dataServices.getBases(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude).success(function (data) {
            $scope.model.baseList = data;
        });
    });
};
```

As you can see in the root controller I get location, then use the location variables in the service I wrote `dataServices.getBases`. I've been able to test that the coordinates are successfully found, and dataServices.getBases is called, but the `$http.get` function doesn't fire. The server side method handling the call is never hit. There's no error, warnings... just nothing.

I have other functions in that service that use $http.get without problems.

Comment: your code seems ok. it is fired. http://jsfiddle.net/KMkhH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from angular 1.1.4 you need to call $http from the context of angular. 
Solution call $apply :

```
// root controller
function RootCtrl($scope, $location, dataServices) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
        dataServices.getBases(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude).success(function (data) {
            $scope.model.baseList = data;
        });
        $scope.$apply(); // ADD this line 
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into that. I'm curious, what does $scope.apply() do in this circumstance? The function `dataServices.getBases` runs fine, but the `$http.get()` inside it doesn't seem to fire. The server-side code the $http.get() is hitting is never hit (I watch in the debugger waiting for incoming requests, and get none). I've tested the url it's trying to hit as well... when manually hitting the url, it works. Strange?

Comment: No. It was planned to support interceptors. Look at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2431#issuecomment-18566595. To make interceptors use promises $http will not work unless from within a digest loop. Or you need to call apply manually as I have shown :)

Comment: Basically you are only registering what $http should do. $http will not fire untill the end of a digest loop. And if you do not run a digest loop mangually it will not fire

Comment: I'm not at my workstation right now, but I will definitely check this out. Thanks for taking the time to answer and explain.

Comment: One more thing... is this because the `$http.get()` is inside the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` function?

Comment: Yes. The browser callbacks are called outside angular world. Same with setTimeout : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2371

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for that... I knew of scope.apply() for model properties, but not for functions like so. Thank you!